# How to bring octave output image within HDFS system

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, octave, hadoop-streaming

I have implemented a octave image processing program. That i should run it in Hadoop environment. I am using hadoop streaming jar file. For instance,

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper /usr/OT/octavebash.sh -file /usr/OT/octavebash.sh -input /usr/OT/2003vellore.jpg -output /usr/OT/outputbash
```

This is the format i have given in hadoop job.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/octave <<EOF
rgbImage = imread("/usr/2003vre.jpg");
imwrite(rgbImage,"/usr/OT/newnewnew.jpg");
```

This is octavebash.sh file. Here I want to write a image in HDFS itself. MapReduce job is 100% completed. But i got nothing like image, I got only the folder named outputbash. Is that right the path I am giving here. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Do those (a) scripts and (b) directories exist on all of the SLAVE NODES / tasktrackers?  MAke sure you are not just looking at the hadoop master node . The real work happens on the slaves.